How do I make my Next and Previous buttons move this carousel? I already got it to slide transition automatically, but can't get manual navigation
I am trying to make a carousel for our company LMS homepage. I want it to automatically transition through each carousel item (the banner images) as well as have it so people can click buttons to navigate back or forward through the carousel items without breaking the automatic timer. I have the automatic slide transitioning working and I have the buttons built for manually navigating. I just can't figure out how to make the buttons work.
I am not too experienced with Javascript and I am guessing that is what I need to get this all working. So, if anyone could help me figure this out, I'd be eternally grateful!
My entire code is below for reference:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link tabindex="11" rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link tabindex="11" rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link tabindex="11" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Condensed:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <style>
    * {box-sizing: border-box}
    body {
    font-family: "Open Sans"; 
    margin:0; 
    white-space: nowrap;

    }


    * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    }

    .carousel_items {
    display: flex;
    overflow: hidden;
    }


    .carousel_item {
    position: relative;
    min-width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    transition: all 0.5s linear;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;


    }
    .carousel_text {
    color: #f2f2f2;
    font-size: 4vh;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 70px;
    width: 26%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: none;
    font-family: "Open Sans";
    font-size: calc(1.5rem + 0.3vw);


    }

    .item1 {
    background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1707218526479-91d005196060?q=80&w=2070&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D");

    }
    .item2 {
    background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1435527173128-983b87201f4d?q=80&w=2067&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D");
    }
    .item3 {
    background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1523655223303-4e9ef5234587?q=80&w=2074&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D");
    }



    .prev, .next {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
    width: auto;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-top: -40px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: calc(1.5rem + 0.3vw);
    transition: 0.6s ease;
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
    user-select: none;
    }


    .next {
    right: 0;
    border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
    }

    .prev:hover, .next:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    }


    @media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
    .prev, .next,.text {font-size: 11px}
    }


        
</style>
</head>
<body>

    
    <div class="carousel-container">
  <div class="carousel_items">
    <div class="carousel_item item1">
      <p class="carousel_text">Featured Training</p>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel_item item2">
      <p class="carousel_text">Activity Calendar</p>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel_item item3">
      <p class="carousel_text">Technical Learning</p>
    </div>
    
  </div>
    <a class="prev"><i class="material-icons">chevron_left</i></a>
        <a class="next"><i class="material-icons">chevron_right</i></a> 
        
</div>

    
    </body>
    
    
    
<script>
    const carouselItems = document.querySelectorAll(".carousel_item"); 
let i = 1;

setInterval(() => {
 Array.from(carouselItems).forEach((item,index) => {
   if(i < carouselItems.length){
    item.style.transform = `translateX(-${i*100}%)`
   }
  })

    
  if(i < carouselItems.length){
    i++;
  }
  else{
    i=0;
  }
},4000)
    
    

    </script>



</html> 


I've tried adding triggers to the buttons but I just am far too inexperienced with Javascript. Trying to implement other people's javascript codes for navigation buttons was too hard to get to work as well. So, I never really got anywhere.
Edit:
Actually, I made some progress. I didnt know Chatgpt could do this. Managed to get somewhat there using chatgpt like iorgu mentioned.
This gets VERY close. Only issue is that it has a random blank banner it transitions too and doesn't transition to my third item, Technical Learning.
Any advice to clean it up? Here is the new script:
const carouselItems = document.querySelectorAll(".carousel_item");
const prevButton = document.querySelector(".prev");
const nextButton = document.querySelector(".next");
let currentIndex = 0;

function goToSlide(index) {
  if (index < 0) {
    index = carouselItems.length - 1;
  } else if (index >= carouselItems.length) {
    index = 0;
  }

  // Slide to the given index
  carouselItems.forEach((item, i) => {
    item.style.transform = `translateX(${(i - index) * 100}%)`;
  });

  currentIndex = index;
}

function slideNext() {
  goToSlide(currentIndex + 1);
}

function slidePrev() {
  goToSlide(currentIndex - 1);
}

// Automatic sliding
setInterval(slideNext, 4000);

// Manual navigation event listeners
prevButton.addEventListener("click", slidePrev);
nextButton.addEventListener("click", slideNext);


I can't give you the correct solution to your problem, but there are few JS Libraries for carousels. I recommend slick.js. This is what I use for my projects. It's easy to use and has a good amount of customization options.

Thanks for the tip. Where can I find the JS Libraries for carousels?

What is plusSlides()?

The plusSlides() is something I tried from another, less advanced carousel I made that I didn't like. I think it was connected to some javascript. I forgot to remove that part when I just copied the code for the buttons. It should look like this now.        chevron_left
chevron_right

Okay, now where is the code you would like to run when the chevrons are clicked?

I don't have that yet. That's what I need help figuring out. I'm not sure where to even start...

@Fourkings13 check out my answer, and let me know if it's what your after.

@iorgu I just made an edit to the main post with a new js code thanks to your advice. I got REALLY close. It works now like I wanted, its just glitchy now. So progress! Just need help cleaning it up so it works properly.

WAIT, no that updated version posted as the answer works PERFECT. Thank you! that's exactly what I needed.

Okay, I'm glad that I could help you.

Glad they could help you. But if you still want to look into it just google slick.js. There is a instruction on how to use and install it.

Here's the updated version:


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link tabindex="11" rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link tabindex="11" rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link tabindex="11" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Condensed:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <style>
    * {box-sizing: border-box}
    body {
    font-family: "Open Sans"; 
    margin:0; 
    white-space: nowrap;
    }

    * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    }

    .carousel_items {
    display: flex;
    overflow: hidden;
    }

    .carousel_item {
    position: relative;
    min-width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    transition: all 0.5s linear;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    }
    .carousel_text {
    color: #f2f2f2;
    font-size: 4vh;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 70px;
    width: 26%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: none;
    font-family: "Open Sans";
    font-size: calc(1.5rem + 0.3vw);
    }

    .item1 {
    background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1707218526479-91d005196060?q=80&w=2070&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D");
    }
    .item2 {
    background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1435527173128-983b87201f4d?q=80&w=2067&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D");
    }
    .item3 {
    background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1523655223303-4e9ef5234587?q=80&w=2074&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D");
    }

    .prev, .next {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
    width: auto;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-top: -40px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: calc(1.5rem + 0.3vw);
    transition: 0.6s ease;
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
    user-select: none;
    }

    .next {
    right: 0;
    border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
    }

    .prev:hover, .next:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
    .prev, .next,.text {font-size: 11px}
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="carousel-container">
        <div class="carousel_items">
            <div class="carousel_item item1">
                <p class="carousel_text">Featured Training</p>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel_item item2">
                <p class="carousel_text">Activity Calendar</p>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel_item item3">
                <p class="carousel_text">Technical Learning</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)"><i class="material-icons">chevron_left</i></a>
        <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)"><i class="material-icons">chevron_right</i></a> 
    </div>
    
    <script>
        let currentSlide = 0;
        const carouselItems = document.querySelectorAll(".carousel_item");

        function showSlide(index) {
            const totalSlides = carouselItems.length;
            if (index >= totalSlides) {
                currentSlide = 0;
            } else if (index < 0) {
                currentSlide = totalSlides - 1;
            } else {
                currentSlide = index;
            }
            Array.from(carouselItems).forEach((item, i) => {
                item.style.transform = `translateX(-${currentSlide * 100}%)`;
            });
        }

        function plusSlides(n) {
            showSlide(currentSlide + n);
        }

        setInterval(() => {
            plusSlides(1);
        }, 4000);

        showSlide(currentSlide);
    </script>
</body>
</html>



To address the issue of the auto-sliding being annoying when manually sliding, we can reset the interval each time a manual slide occurs. This way, the auto-sliding will pause and then resume after a fixed period of time. Here's the updated code with this behavior implemented:


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link tabindex="11" rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link tabindex="11" rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link tabindex="11" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Condensed:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <style>
    * {box-sizing: border-box}
    body {
    font-family: "Open Sans"; 
    margin:0; 
    white-space: nowrap;
    }

    * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    }

    .carousel_items {
    display: flex;
    overflow: hidden;
    }

    .carousel_item {
    position: relative;
    min-width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    transition: all 0.5s linear;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    }
    .carousel_text {
    color: #f2f2f2;
    font-size: 4vh;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 70px;
    width: 26%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: none;
    font-family: "Open Sans";
    font-size: calc(1.5rem + 0.3vw);
    }

    .item1 {
    background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1707218526479-91d005196060?q=80&w=2070&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D");
    }
    .item2 {
    background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1435527173128-983b87201f4d?q=80&w=2067&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D");
    }
    .item3 {
    background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1523655223303-4e9ef5234587?q=80&w=2074&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D");
    }

    .prev, .next {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
    width: auto;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-top: -40px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: calc(1.5rem + 0.3vw);
    transition: 0.6s ease;
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
    user-select: none;
    }

    .next {
    right: 0;
    border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
    }

    .prev:hover, .next:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
    .prev, .next,.text {font-size: 11px}
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="carousel-container">
        <div class="carousel_items">
            <div class="carousel_item item1">
                <p class="carousel_text">Featured Training</p>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel_item item2">
                <p class="carousel_text">Activity Calendar</p>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel_item item3">
                <p class="carousel_text">Technical Learning</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)"><i class="material-icons">chevron_left</i></a>
        <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)"><i class="material-icons">chevron_right</i></a> 
    </div>
    
    <script>
        let currentSlide = 0;
        const carouselItems = document.querySelectorAll(".carousel_item");
        let autoSlideInterval;

        function showSlide(index) {
            const totalSlides = carouselItems.length;
            if (index >= totalSlides) {
                currentSlide = 0;
            } else if (index < 0) {
                currentSlide = totalSlides - 1;
            } else {
                currentSlide = index;
            }
            Array.from(carouselItems).forEach((item, i) => {
                item.style.transform = `translateX(-${currentSlide * 100}%)`;
            });
        }

        function plusSlides(n) {
            showSlide(currentSlide + n);
            resetAutoSlide();
        }

        function startAutoSlide() {
            autoSlideInterval = setInterval(() => {
                plusSlides(1);
            }, 4000);
        }

        function resetAutoSlide() {
            clearInterval(autoSlideInterval);
            startAutoSlide();
        }

        // Start the auto-sliding
        startAutoSlide();

        // Initialize the first slide
        showSlide(currentSlide);
    </script>
</body>
</html>




The auto-sliding may be annoying when sliding manually: The interval could be reset upon button press, or briefly deactivated.
